# How can I search a container of objects for a data member value?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, c++03

I have an object type like this:

```
struct T
{
   int x;
   bool y;
};
```

and a container of them like this:

```
std::vector<T> v;
```

and a burning desire to determine — *in a single statement* — whether any of the elements of `v` have `y == true`. This likely involves `std::find_if`.

My understanding is that `std::bind` and `boost::bind` are for member *functions* and cannot be applied to member data.

---

Because I dislike them, I wish to avoid:

- comparison functions/functors
- loops

Because my environment is C++03, the following are not available:

- lambdas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My understanding is that `std::bind` and `boost::bind` are for member *functions* and cannot be applied to member data.

Remarkably, this is not the case! `boost::bind` will happily bind to member data and allow you to perform operations on it during an "inline iteration".

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers):

> Pointers to member functions and pointers to data members are not function objects, because they do not support `operator()`. For convenience, **bind** accepts member pointers as its first argument, and the behavior is as if [boost::mem_fn](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html) has been used to convert the member pointer into a function object. In other words, the expression
>
> ```
> bind(&X::f, args)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> bind<R>(mem_fn(&X::f), args)
> ```
>
> where **R** is the return type of **X::f** (for member functions) or the type of the member (for data members.)

Also, from the documentation for `boost::mem_fn`:

> mem_fn also supports pointers to data members by treating them as functions taking no arguments and returning a (const) reference to the member.

So, you can do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct T
{
   int x;
   bool y;
};

void f(const std::string& name, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
   const bool found = std::find_if(
      v.begin(),
      v.end(),
      boost::bind(&T::y, _1) == true
   ) != v.end();

   std::cout << name << ": " << (found ? " FOUND" : " not found") << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   T a = { 0, false };
   T b = { 1, false };
   T c = { 2, true  };

   std::vector<T> v;
   f("a", v);

   v.push_back(a);
   v.push_back(b);
   f("b", v);

   v.push_back(c);
   f("c", v);
}
```

Output:

> a:  not found
>   b:  not found
>   c:  FOUND

Comment: Ah, amazing! This is such a pleasant surprise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want (to determine — in a single statement — whether any of the elements of v have y == true) seems to be:

```
inline bool y_is_true(std::vector<T>::iterator i) { return i->y; };
```

(outside your function) and

```
bool found = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), y_is_true) != v.end();
```

Another option is to use `boost::lambda`:

```
bool found = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), _1.y) != v.end();
```

Comment: Defining the functor then performing the search is _two_ statements. However, that `boost::lambda` approach is very interesting and I'm going to have to look into that! Thanks.