# Member variable doesn't get changed in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've asked a question a few minutes ago and now I've got a new problem.
I've got a code like this:

```
class foo{
public:

    void loop(){
        this->running = true;

        while(this->running){
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    void exitLoop(){
        this->running = false;
    }

private:

    bool running;
};

int main(){
    foo theFoo = foo(); 

    thread fooLoop(&foo::loop, theFoo);

    // do stuff

    theFoo.exitLoop();

    fooLoop.join();
}
```

When I'm calling `theFoo.exitLoop()`, `running` should be set to `false` and the loop/thread should exit. But when I'm calling `exitLoop()`, the while-loop just continues. When I'm checking the value of `running` inside the loop, I'm getting `true`, but it should be `false`, so that the loop exits.

When I'm not using a member variable but a global one, everything works fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `atomic<bool>` to avoid race condition, or you can use `std::conditional_variable`, so you don't burn your cpu.

Comment: You seem to be blundering through a series of wild guesses about how to write multi-threaded code. Perhaps try learning from a book, instead...?

Comment: @yngum In the full code, I can be sure that `running` gets set to `false` after the thread is created. :)

Comment: @Jarod42: No, it should be atomic, or protected by a mutex, or synchronised in some other way. `volatile` isn't sufficient for sharing between threads.

Comment: @Jarod42: Mutexes must provide the necessary synchronisation, otherwise they'd be useless. Standard C++ mutexes certainly do. The only use of `volatile` is a warning that the author doesn't understand threading.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: With `mutex`, we can force that the read/write is not 'simultaneous', `volatile` forces to re-read the value (and so avoid to cache the value in register for example). There are complementary.

Comment: @Jarod42: The mutex introduces the necessary memory barrier(s), and values mustn't be cached across memory barriers. `volatile` adds nothing to that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44961/discussion-between-jarod42-and-mike-seymour)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're binding a copy of `theFoo` to the thread; so calling `exitLoop` on the local copy does nothing to the copy used by the thread. Instead, you could bind a pointer:

```
thread fooLoop(&foo::loop, &theFoo);
```

or a (wrapped) reference:

```
thread fooLoop(&foo::loop, std::ref(theFoo));
```

or use a lambda and capture by reference:

```
thread fooLoop([&]{theFoo.loop();});
```

You could also prevent mistakes like this by making the class uncopyable:

```
class foo {
    foo(foo const &) = delete;             // delete the copy constructor
    void operator=(foo const &) = delete;  // delete the copy-assignment operator

    // ...
};
```

You also have a race condition: if `exitLoop` is called before the thread starts, then the thread will set `running` back to `true` and run forever. You should probably set the flag in the constructor. The flag should also be atomic, or protected by a mutex, to synchronise the update.

Comment: Thank you very much :) In programming, for the biggest problems, there's a simple solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand how it even compiled. That bound parameter should be a pointer, no? I suppose it could pass compilation and head into UB territory by chance since there's not much member writing going on.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit The codes I'm posting are just examples, minimized versions of my code. And yes it compiles when I'm not passing a pointer. If the example code compiles? I don't know, but it did it's job: Getting me an answer. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The first parameter bound to a member function can be either a pointer or an object, surely? (The standard is even more opaque than usual when it describes binding, but I'm pretty sure that's the case).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It's news to me, but I'll believe it if you say so!

Comment: 30.3.1.2/4 defines the arguments in terms of `INVOKE`; 20.8.2/1 says you're right. 20.8.9.1.2/3 says the same for `std::bind`. Mind blown. Perhaps I spent too long thinking of `boost::bind`... [which it turns out _also_ supports this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions). ([Related nonsense from me where I found out something else about `bind`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17196690/560648))

Comment: Why the thread constructor allows to pass a copy is beyond me. There might be a very good reason for that, but right now I can't think of any that would offset the danger of messing up your code so badly and without even a warning for a mere forgotten `&`. Looks like a guy selling you a loaded elephant gun and saying "you might want to add a safety catch, if you feel like it and know how to. Anyway, happy hunting!".

Comment: @kuroineko: C++ _is_ a loaded elephant gun with optional safety catches. Binding to a copy is useful if you want to detach the thread and leave the function that created it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour God am I glad to (try to) make do with these BBguns of JS and PHP for a living :) I have no doubt passing a copy can be useful, I only wonder why they did not manage to achieve that with an explicit, different and unambiguous interface. Would have ruined the looks of the whole thing, I suppose...

Comment: @kuroineko You're implementing the `std::thread` constructor. How can you possibly send the constructor parameters - which have automatic storage duration - to the new thread without making a copy? You can't exactly send references to objects that will cease to exist when the constructor returns.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix this issue about copying this object, you cannot use a bool like that for synchronization.  An optimizing compiler might notice that `this->running` won't be modified within that loop, and might conclude there is no need to check its value over and over again.  In fact the loop code has no business taking other threads into account at all, it could just ignore them.  You have to use atomic_bool instead.

Comment: Or even bettter: don't synchronize your threads with glorified flags. It might look like the easy way out, but without a minimal grasp of what concurrent execution and synchronization really means, you'll find yourself up sh...err.. bug creek with no paddle in no time.